# Why Bootstrap CSS is being bundled together with Javascript when using MiniCssExtractPlugin?

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-4, css-loader, less-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm trying to generate the vendors CSS and Javascript, but something is going wrong. The vendor Css is being included in both Css and Javascript bundle.

Here's my webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = (env) => {

  const optimization = {
    noEmitOnErrors: true,
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        polyfills: {
          name: 'polyfills',
          test: /polyfills|core-js|zone/,
          chunks: 'initial',
          priority: 2,
          enforce: true,
        },
        vendors: {
          name: 'vendors',
          test: /node_modules/,
          chunks: 'all',
          priority: 1,
          enforce: true,
        },
        appStyles: {
          name: 'app',
          test: (m, c, entry = 'app') => m.constructor.name === 'CssModule' && recursiveIssuer(m) === entry,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        },
        vendorsStyles: {
          name: 'vendors',
          test: (m, c, entry = 'vendors') => m.constructor.name === 'CssModule' && recursiveIssuer(m) === entry,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        }
      }
    },
  };

  return {
    optimization,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
      app: helpers.root('/client/src/main.ts'),
      vendors: helpers.root('/client/src/vendors.ts'),
      polyfills: helpers.root('/client/src/polyfills.ts'),
    },
    output: {
      path: helpers.root('/client-dist'),
      filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
      modules: [
        helpers.root('/client/src'),
        helpers.root('/node_modules'),
      ],
      alias: rxPaths(),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
          include: helpers.root('/client/src'),
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: ['html-loader'],
          include: helpers.root('/client/src'),
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            CssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
          ],
          include: helpers.root('/node_modules/bootstrap'),
        },
        {
          test: /\.less$/,
          use: [
            CssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
            'less-loader',
          ],
          include: helpers.root('/client/src/assets/styles'),
        },            
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanPlugin(['client-dist'], {root: helpers.root('/')}),
      new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({debug: true}),
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/@angular\/core\/fesm5/, helpers.root('/client/src')),
      new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
      new CssExtractPlugin({filename: 'assets/styles/[name].css'}),
      new HtmlPlugin({template: helpers.root('/client/src/index.html')}),
    ],
  };
};
```

And this is the vendors.ts entry:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

This results in a vendors.css including bootstrap.min.css, but bootstra.min.css is also included in vendors.js. How can I separate this?

Comment: I'm glad you found out there was no actual problem!
Maybe it'd be more appropriate to close the question, as it isn't really reproducible.

Comment: @codeBelt, I'm my case it seems that the css is removed from the bundle. I search for the term bootstrap and the only relevant result is the occurrence I posted in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue. For `css-loader` I had `modules` set to `true` which caused the bootstrap css to be added to the JavaScript vendor file.

```
{
    test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
    use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                modules: false, // If this is true then I see the issue
                camelCase: 'dashes',
                minimize: isProduction,
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: !isProduction
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems to be a bug in Webpack bundle analyzer tool I'm using to check the bundles.

[image]

But bootstrap.min.css was removed from the vendor.js:

[image]

Comment: I have this same problem https://github.com/codeBelt/webpack-4-starter and I am not using Webpack bundle analyzer.

Comment: @codeBelt, but did you check your bundle? In my case the css was removed by mini css text extractor.